# Bug with a program for a guessing game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a program where a user had to guess a random number in a specific range and has 3 tries to do so. After each try, if the guess is correct you tell the user they won and if the guess is wrong you tell them its wrong and how many tries they have got remaining. When the number of tries exceed 3 without a correct guess, you tell the user they are out of tries and tell them they lost. When the program finishes after a correct or 3 wrong tries and the game is over, you ask if the user wants to play again. If they say "yes", you star the game again and if they say "no", you end the game.
This is the code I have come up with:

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
while guess != True:
    if tries<=3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if tries<3:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! Try again."
                tries = tries + 1
                print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
        if tries>2:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
                print "Game Over!"
again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
if again == "no":
    print "Okay thanks for playing!"
elif again =="yes":
    print "Great!"
```

Now when you guess the correct number before 3 tries, the program seems to be working fine, but even when the number of wrong tries exceeds 3, the program keeps asking for more guesses but I want it to stop the program right there. The second thing I don't get is how do I start the whole game again when the user wants to play again? 
How can I modify my code to fix these errors?

Comment: Just curious: why not use any functions?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is it. Tested this out. Working Perfect (Y)

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
while guess != True:
    if tries<=3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if tries<3:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! Try again."
                tries = tries + 1
                print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
        if tries>2:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
                print "Game Over!"
                again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
                if again == "no":
                    guess = True
                    print "Okay thanks for playing!"
                elif again =="yes":
                    tries = 0
                    print "Great!"
```

Hope this helps.

Here's more compact code you can try. Also it is solving your "Wrong Guess. Try Again." issue on last guess.

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
print x
while guess != True:
    while tries<3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if inp == x:
            guess = True
            print "Correct! You won"
            break
        else:
            tries = tries + 1
            if tries == 3:
                break
            print "Wrong guess! Try again."
            print "Your remaining tries are", (3 - tries)

        if not guess:
            print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
            print "Game Over!"
        again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if again == "no":
            guess = True
            print "Okay thanks for playing!"
        elif again == "yes":
            tries = 0
            if guess:
                guess = False
                x = round(random.random() * 5)
            print "Great!"
```

Comment: wont the statements after the line in which we initialise again be right next to the wall and not indented?

Comment: To continue the game, it has to be inside the loop. Otherwise when user Enters "yes" the game will not continue. Game will only terminates when user enters "no". Hope you are getting this.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I did not read that you set tries to 0 in the second last statement. But yes this works perfectly now! Just one issue, when we input the third try it ouutputs "Wrong guess! Try again.
Your remaining tries are 0
Wrong guess! You are out of tries
Game Over!" when i just want it to say "Wrong guess! You are out of tries" "Game Over" after the third wrong try.

Comment: Just tested your new code. Works perfect when guesses are wrong, but when you give the right guess, the program doest stop ask for you to play again, it asks for the rest of the tries.

Comment: Same problem still. Program ends after a correct guess.

Comment: Apologies again. But this time it's good to go. You will be able to get new random no. on next play. Hope your issues end here. :)

Comment: actually this code doesn't do what we want at all, lots of bugs. haven't you run the code yourself before you posted it?

Comment: Comment me the bugs I'll fix them all. Ran but I think didn't go through all possible tracks.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to stop a loop when some condition becomes true is to use `break`. So when the player guesses correctly, the code would look like

```
if inp == x:
    guess = True
    print "Correct! You won"
    break
```

Additionally, you should break the loop when you run out of guesses, otherwise it will keep running

```
else:
    print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
    print "Game Over!"
    break
```

To let the player play again, you can have a variable `playing` and use it in a while loop that wraps the whole game, and when they say they don't want to play anymore, make it `False` so that the outer loop ends.

```
playing = True
while playing:
    x = round(random.random()*5)
    guess = False
    tries = 0
    while guess != True:
        ...

    again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
    if again == "no":
        print "Okay thanks for playing!"
        playing = False
    elif again =="yes":
        print "Great!"
```

As you noted in comments on another answer, when the player gets their third guess wrong, the game tells them they have 0 guesses left and to try again, and then tells them they are out of tries and that the game is over. Since you want it to only tell them they are out of tries and that the game is over, you can change the main block of code to:

```
while guess != True:
    inp = input("Guess the number: ")
    if inp == x:
        guess = True
        print "Correct! You won"
    else:
        tries = tries + 1
        if tries == 3:
            print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
            print "Game Over!"
            break
        else:
            print "Wrong guess! Try again."
            print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
```

Comment: @HogRider123, updated to fix the issue with printing the wrong thing on the third wrong guess.

Answer (score 2):

this is a slightly different version to your problem:

```
import random

def play():
    x = round(random.random()*5)
    guess = False
    tries = 0
    while guess is False and tries < 3:
        inp = raw_input("Guess the number: ")
        if int(inp) == x:
            guess = True
            print "Correct! You won" 
        else:
            print "Wrong guess! Try again." 
            tries = tries + 1
            print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
            if tries == 3:
                print("Game Over!")

play()
again = "maybe"
while again != "no":
    again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? yes OR no? \n")
    if again == "yes":
        print "Great!"
        play()
print "Okay thanks for playing!"
```

Comment: This also works just fine.Basically I was looking to write my program without defining any functions. But thanks mate!

Comment: ah.. oh well :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make guess equal to `True` in your second `else` or else it will never satisfy stop condition for while loop. Do you understand?

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
while guess != True:
    if tries<=3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if tries<3:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            elif tries+1 != 3:
                print "Wrong guess! Try again."
                print "Your remaining tries are",(3-(tries+1))
            tries = tries + 1    
        if tries>2:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
                print "Game Over!"
                guess= True

                again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
                if again == "no":
                    print "Okay thanks for playing!"
                elif again =="yes":
                    print "Great!"
                    guess = False
                    tries = 0
```

EDIT: I think this does the trick using your code.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake I didnt see, thanks for pointing that out. But theres still a problem, because when the number of tries is reached. It first says "Wrong guess! Try again"  "Your remaining tries are 0"  and then it says "You are out of tries, game over"

Comment: I want it to just say "You are out of tries, game over" when the limit of tries is reached.

Comment: @HogRider123 That is because the two `if`s are separate, so when it adds 1 to `tries` so that `tries` is 3, the second `if` will run right away. To avoid this, you could change the second `if` to `elif`

Comment: @jonhopkins adding an elif to the if you said will create an extra number of tries.

Comment: You're right. Misinterpreted what you wanted. Updating my answer to fix this.

Comment: @SeanM great work to eliminate that error, but still with your code, if the user says they want to play again, the number of tries given to the user will only be one because the loop will break immediately. I hope you are getting what i am trying to say.

Comment: Add `tries = 0` to last `elif`

Comment: @SeanM wont the program terminate after there is a correct guess now?

Comment: Yes. But you could put the same block of code for asking if the user wants to play again in  the body of the `if`

Answer (score 1):

You need to move where you set guess = True

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
while guess != True:
    if tries<=3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if tries<3:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! Try again."
                tries = tries + 1
                print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
        if tries>2:
            guess = True
            if inp == x:   
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
                print "Game Over!"
again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
if again == "no":
    print "Okay thanks for playing!"
elif again =="yes":
    print "Great!"
```

Before you were only ending on the condition where the last guess was correct. You should be ending whether the guess was correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update tries.  Additionally you need to break out of your loop even if guess != True

```
import random
x =round(random.random()*5)
guess = False
tries = 0
while guess != True:
    if tries<=3:
        inp = input("Guess the number: ")
        if tries<3:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! Try again."
                tries = tries + 1
                print "Your remaining tries are",(3-tries)
        if tries>2:
            if inp == x:
                guess = True
                print "Correct! You won"
            else:
                print "Wrong guess! You are out of tries"
                print "Game Over!"
                break
    tries += 1
again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ")
if again == "no":
    print "Okay thanks for playing!"
elif again =="yes":
    print "Great!"
```