# How Do I Make This Python Guessing Game Start Again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add some code to the end of this guessing game which will ask the user if they want to play again. If they say yes, the program will, I suppose, just run again from the beginning. I've tried multiple ideas, but none have worked. The closest was another if loop at the end. Thank you! x

```
print("Welcome to this guessing game!")

import random

x = random.randrange(50)

guess = int(input("I've picked an integer between 1 to 99. Guess what it is: "))

while x != "guess":

print
if guess < x:
    print("Your guess is too low!")
    guess = int(input("Guess again:"))
elif guess > x:
    print("Your guess is too high!")
    guess = int(input("Guess again:"))
else:
    print ("You guessed the right number!")
```

Comment: Try another `while` loop.

Comment: use a while loop.

while keepPlaying == true){
*ask if they wanna keep playing*
if no then set keepPlaying=false
)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug with a program for a guessing game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902412/bug-with-a-program-for-a-guessing-game)

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
while True:
    your code

    if input("Continue? Y/N: ").lower() not in {"y", "yes"}:
        break
```

At the end of every play, this gets input from the user, converts it to lower case, and sees if it's "y" or "yes". If it's not, the game breaks out of the loop, i.e. quits. Otherwise it keeps looping.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your game in a function. And then on user say "yes", you invoke the function. And at the end of you game, reask the samequestion.

This is what function is made for.

Pseudo code:

```
   function askUser(){
    'Do you want to play'=>yes: launchGame, no:print("ok bye bye")
    }

    function myGame(){
    //your game
        askUser()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
import random
something="yes"

while(something == "yes"):
#your code...
#....
#from your code
else:
    print ("You guessed the right number!")
    something=input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)")#input return str? I use raw_input all the time in p2.7
```

and this:

```
while x != "guess":
```

why to guess use " "?

x = random.randrange(50) so x never being a string "guess" its like while True: or while 1:

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to this guessing game!")

import random

x = random.randrange(50)

guess = int(input("I've picked an integer between 1 to 99. Guess what it is: "))

while True:

    if guess < x:
        print("Your guess is too low!")
        guess = int(input("Guess again:"))
    elif guess > x:
        print("Your guess is too high!")
        guess = int(input("Guess again:"))
    else:
        print ("You guessed the right number!")
        break
```

You are learning about the basics of python too little advice to read more books
x is the type of int and guess you use "" included "guess" he is not a variable name and become a string